# Can someone explain how this code sorts in ascending order?

Tags: ruby, arrays, function, sorting

It returns the array/list in ascending order, but how does it work?

```
books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]

books.sort! { |firstBook, secondBook| firstBook <=> secondBook }
```

Comment: May be Ruby using sorting algorithms to sort array. See this http://www.sitepoint.com/sorting-algorithms-ruby/

Comment: And you don't need the block to sort in ascending order. `books.sort!` will do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question with a simple answer. The block calls the spaceship operator: `<=>`. Many objects respond to it. It returns -1, 0, or 1 depending whether one object is "greater" than the other.

Here is how it works for strings:

> Comparison—Returns -1, 0, +1 or nil depending on whether string is
>   less than, equal to, or greater than other_string.
>
> If the strings are of different lengths, and the strings are equal
>   when compared up to the shortest length, then the longer string is
>   considered greater than the shorter one.

If you have an object that does not respond to the spaceship operator (like your own objects), then you can define it yourself.

[Ruby Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)

Comment: I doubt this is an answer to the question “how does sorting work”.

Comment: I didn't think the question is 'how does sorting work". I think it is more about explaining blocks or the spaceship operator.

Comment: I want to know that how does "THIS" code work to sort the array?

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable#sort` [uses](https://www.igvita.com/2009/03/26/ruby-algorithms-sorting-trie-heaps/) the well-known [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm.

The comparison callback you provide in block (`firstBook <=> secondBook`) is being called by ruby default quicksort implementation.